# Why am I getting a "segmentation fault 11" when I have assigned enough memory?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have created double pointer char to be used as a 2d array to store strings. The append function is meant to add the string provided to the end of the array, the num_strings pointer is provided to keep track of the elements in the array (since I can't use sizeof). It seems that at some point, the function isn't allocating enough memory but I can't seem to figure out where and can't find any other issues.

I have already tried giving both the outer array and the inner array large amounts of memory, much more than they need. The issue persists. I have also tried copying the string to the array after the function had run.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **strings = NULL;
    int num_strings = 0;

    append(&strings, &num_strings, "Alex");
    append(&strings, &num_strings, "Edward");

    // Do things with array

    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {;
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    // Free memory after use

    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
        free(strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);
    strings = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void append(char ***array, int * num_strings, char *string) {


    if (*array == NULL) {
        *array = malloc(sizeof(*array)); // start with enough room for 1 item (pointer)
    } else {
        // reallocate memory for new item
        *array = realloc(*array, (((*num_strings) + 1) * sizeof(*array)));

    }

    printf("Char Size: %lu\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Given Size: %lu\n", sizeof(***(array)));

    *(array[*num_strings]) = malloc((strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(***(array + 0)));

    strcpy(*(array[*num_strings]), string);

    (*num_strings)++; // increment the number of strings
}
```

The output of the program should be the two strings, at the moment it only prints the first and then crashs due to the segmentation fault.

Comment: I find this code nearly illegible. Are you sure this is the best approach?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I intentionally chose to mix up *(array + i) and array[i] to help myself learn. I will change it all to array[i]. I will try and clean up the function as well if that helps.

Comment: You're using `sizeof(*array)`, where you need `sizeof(**array)`.  `x = malloc(sizeof(x))` is never correct, even if `x` is `*y`.  Check all of your `malloc` sizes.  There are definite errors here.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, I have made the change but the issue persists. It seems that realloc (my only other memory management function) does have the correct triple dereference that it should have. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your problem is here:  Change `*(array[*num_strings])` to `(*array)[*num_strings]`.  You have this in a couple places.

Comment: @TomKarzes What is the different between the two? Edit: Thank you so much, it seems to have fixed the issue. Please post an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are a couple instances of `*(array[*num_strings])` that should be `(*array)[*num_strings]`.

The difference is that the first form tries to index through the pointer passed to the function, as if the passed `strings` were an array, corrupting the caller's stack.  The corrected version first derefernces the pointer, then indexed through the target as desired.

There are also a few places where `sizeof(*array)` is used where it should be `sizeof(**array)`. `x = malloc(sizeof(x))` is never correct.  But this isn't causing a visible problem.